# how to add spring security in login form

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a login page with email address and password. How can i use spring security for the secure login. I'm don't understand how to do it..? In my web app the first page is the login page with  with userEmail and Password.

This is my jsp page

```
<form:form action="/pname/signin" modelAttribute="user"  method="post" id="form" >
  <form:input path="userEmailId"  placeholder="User Name"  />
  <form:password path="userPassword"  placeholder="Password"  />
  <a href="signin" class="anchorStyle"><input type="submit" value="signin"/> </a>
</form:form>
```

and here is my spring-security.xml

```
 <http auto-config="true">  
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />  
    <logout logout-success-url="/signin?logout" />
 </http>  

 <authentication-manager>  
   <authentication-provider>  
     <user-service>  
       <user name="user" password="password" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />  
     </user-service>  
   </authentication-provider>  
 </authentication-manager>
```

Please tell me where my mistake is. Also after a success login it should go the hello page.

Comment: can you add the JSP that shows the form?

Comment: @Jeroen..i added it..please tell me ..i m using json for this..

Comment: Can you describe what isn't working? Do you get to the login page? Do you get any exceptions when trying to authenticate?

Comment: Actually i dont know what to put in the name and password parameter in spring-security.xml,because if i am entering valid username n password which are present at the remote server it should give me successful login.n for other it should give me error.n again i m getting error as when i put <form:form action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check'/>" method="post"> it showing me error as request not found.

Answer (score 1):

[This tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-example/), and [this tutorial](http://orcunyilmaz.com/coding-java/spring/baby-steps-on-spring-security.html) can help you. You basicly define necessary informations to be checked in the background, like userEmail and userPassword in your **.xml** file.

After that, in your **.jsp** file, you are giving url value as **j_spring_security_check** to match up your password with your e-mail parameter, and also the **authorization**, to see if that user has that authorization to open some pages that you provide in your web app.

See this example to enlighten you:
This is the **.jsp** view page:

```
<c:if test="${not empty msg}">
                <div class="msg">${msg}</div>
            </c:if>
            <form name="loginForm" action="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_check"/> " method="post">
                <c:if test="${not empty error}">
                    <div class="error" style="color: #ff0000;">${error}</div>
                </c:if>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="userEmail">E-Posta</label>
                    <input id="userEmail" type="email" class="form-control" name="userEmail" placeholder="E-Mail Here!" required>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="userPassword">Şifre</label>
                    <input id="userPassword" type="password" class="form-control" name="userPassword" placeholder="Give me your Password!" required>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-send-message pull-right">GİRİŞ</button>
                </div>

                <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
            </form>
```

This is **security.xml** file:

```
<security:http auto-config="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/addPost/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
    <security:form-login
        login-page="/login"
        default-target-url="/addPost/"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
        username-parameter="userEmail"
        password-parameter="userPassword" />
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                                    authorities-by-username-query="SELECT userEmail, authority FROM AUTHORITIES WHERE userEmail = ?"
                                    users-by-username-query="SELECT userEmail, userPassword, isActive FROM USERS WHERE userEmail = ?"
        />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

As far as I can see from your code, you didn't add any **j_spring_security_check** as a value **.jsp** view. So your code doesn't know where to go for matchup the credentials. And also I believe you should add ***form-login*** to your **.xml** file too, to give directions for your login process.

Hope this helps to you.

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login) should get you going. From the available information it's still hard to figure out what is missing from your configuration. The tutorial explains how you can restrict acces to every page except the login page. It also shows how to forwards to the target page after a sucessfull login. See for instance this http configuration:

```
<http use-expressions="true">
  <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="isAnonymous()" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>

  <form-login
     login-page='/login.html'
     default-target-url="/homepage.html"
     authentication-failure-url="/login.html?error=true" />

  <logout logout-success-url="/login.html" />

</http>
```

Comment: i m using json..how that spring security will get to know that i m enetring right username ad password?